# Convert a python value from string to integer

Tags: python

Is there any possible direct way to convert `345.`, which is actually a `str` type, to `int` type?

I tried `int('345.')` but it gives:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '345.'`

Comment: The problem is the dot in the end of the number. int('345`) would work

Comment: It isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not very elegant, but does what you want without modifying your string:

```
int(float('345.'))
```

Comment: While this solves this specific problem, this is not a generally good solution, because it can lead to loss of precision for larger integers.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly solution, but works :)

```
int('365.'.split('.')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is understandable first delete the last char then convert it to float.

```
fl = "345."
fl = fl[:-1]
fl = float(fl)
```